# Putting output in R into excel

Tags: r, excel, import, export

Guys I have a code that generates 2 columns of data (e.g Number, Median) which refers to a particular person...but I have taken samples of 7 people
so basically I get this output:

```
[[1]
Number Median
1       5
2       3  
.....
[[2]]
Number Median
1       6
2       4
....
[[3]]
Number Median
1       3
2       5
```

So I basically get this output....up til [[7]]
I tried transferring this output in excel using this code

```
write.csv(cbind(data),"data1.csv")
```

and I get this type of output:

```
list(c(Median =.......It lists all the median on the rows
```

But I want it to save the data referring to the 'median' and 'Number' in columns NOT ROWS

If I just type

```
write.csv(data,"data1.csv")
```

I get an error

```
arguments imply differing number of rows: 157, 179, 178, 180
```

Comment: You need your data to be a in a dataframe format within R before you try to write it out as a csv. If your list is called `data`, then something like `one_big_dataframe = do.call(rbind, data)` should get you there.

Answer (score 2):

As Marius said, you have a `list` of `data.frames` which can't be written to a `.csv` file. You need to do:

```
NewDataFrame <- do.call("rbind", YourList)
write.csv(NewDataFrame, "Data.csv")
```

`do.call` takes each of the elements from a `list` and applies whatever function you tell it (in this case `rbind`) to all of them.

Comment: Thanks Senor and Marius.....but I was wondering is there a way that it could look something like this in excel:Number, Speed...Number, Speed...and so...instead of putting everything in just 2 columns

Comment: Then use `"cbind"` instead of `"rbind"`

Comment: I get an error like this if I did that 'arguments imply differing number of rows: 59, 56'

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options. Both use the following sample data:

```
myList <- list(data.frame(matrix(1:4, ncol = 2)),
               data.frame(matrix(3:10, ncol = 2)),
               data.frame(matrix(11:14, ncol =2)))
myList
# [[1]]
#   X1 X2
# 1  1  3
# 2  2  4
# 
# [[2]]
#   X1 X2
# 1  3  7
# 2  4  8
# 3  5  9
# 4  6 10
# 
# [[3]]
#   X1 X2
# 1 11 13
# 2 12 14
```

#### Option 1: Write a csv file where the `data.frame`s are presented as they are in the `list`

```
sink("list_of_dataframes.csv", type="output")
invisible(lapply(myList, function(x) dput(write.csv(x))))
sink()
```

If you open the resulting "list_of_dataframes.csv" file in a text editor, you will get something that looks like this. When you read this into a spreadsheet program, the first column will include the rownames and `NULL` separating each `data.frame`:

```
"","X1","X2"
"1",1,3
"2",2,4
NULL
"","X1","X2"
"1",3,7
"2",4,8
"3",5,9
"4",6,10
NULL
"","X1","X2"
"1",11,13
"2",12,14
NULL
```

#### Option 2: Write or search around for a version of `cbind` that accommodates binding `data.frame`s with differing number of rows.

Here is one such function that I've written.

```
cbind2 <- function(datalist) {
  nrows <- max(sapply(datalist, nrow))
  expandmyrows <- function(mydata, rowsneeded) {
    temp1 = names(mydata)
    rowsneeded = rowsneeded - nrow(mydata)
    temp2 = setNames(data.frame(
      matrix(rep(NA, length(temp1) * rowsneeded),
             ncol = length(temp1))), temp1)
    rbind(mydata, temp2)
  }
  do.call(cbind, lapply(datalist, expandmyrows, rowsneeded = nrows))
}
```

And here is that function applied to your list:

```
cbind2(myList)
#   X1 X2 X1 X2 X1 X2
# 1  1  3  3  7 11 13
# 2  2  4  4  8 12 14
# 3 NA NA  5  9 NA NA
# 4 NA NA  6 10 NA NA
```

That output should be easy for you to use with `write.csv` and related functions.