# Exporting data.frame from R with different number of rows

Tags: r, csv

I have two datasets from two different experiments. The correlation study was performed between these two datasets using Canonical Correlation Analysis (CCA package in R). R had generated correlation plots. Now, I need to export the correlation matrix which was used to generate the plots. I ran the following command:

```
write.csv(correl, file = "correl.csv")
```

and got the following error

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = 
  TRUE,  : arguments imply differing number of rows: 35, 63, 98
```

Please suggest me how I can export the file.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Most likely explanation is that `correl` is not a simple matrix object (*e.g.* is a list of matrices). What does `class(correl)` output?

Comment: What @neilfws says seems likely given other questions with the same error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236179/putting-output-in-r-into-excel

Comment: Try `write` instead?